# Java Quartz-scheduler between time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have job which i want to start using quartz scheduler (v2.1.5) in specific time everyday (eg. 8am-10am with interval 5 min) with no using cron expression, just native methods. (by native methods i understand implemented in that quartz lib). 
I have Trigger:

```
TriggerBuilder builder = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity(name, group)
                .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInMilliseconds(interval)
                        .repeatForever());
```

Of course cron expression dosent make difficult and I can use it instead. But anyway i just would know if using native methods in that problem is possible. Happy to any advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from the [Quartz tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04.html) (modified a bit):

```
var cal = new DailyCalendar(8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0); // range start and end hours, minutes, seconds and millis
cal.setInvertTimerange(true); // by default the date interval specified above is excluded from execution. 
// This turns it around and only allows execution within the interval

var t2 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("myTrigger2")
    .forJob("myJob2")
    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInMilliseconds(interval)
                    .repeatForever());
    .modifiedByCalendar(cal)
    .build();
```

The trick is to have a simple trigger (like you showed above) but then have a calendar implementation that can specify times when execution of that trigger is allowed.

Comment: Great thanks for answer! Unfortunately it dosent solve my problem. I want to run job with schedule between time 8am and 10 am with some interval (eg. 5 secs) so it more execute than one. I want to repeat that every day.

Comment: @Xavizo i updated the answer - that should work for you.

Comment: @MatthiasHuttar It seems DailyCalendar is what i was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The API methods cover several simple (every X, at X) and not-so-simple (days A, B, C at X, monthly at X) scenarios, but yours is a bit beyond that.
You could try this to get a job scheduled to run every 5 minutes, 8am to 10am:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() // identity, job, etc.
        .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                .withIntervalInMinutes(5)
                .repeatForever())
        .startAt(DateBuilder.tomorrowAt(8,0,0))
        .endAt(DateBuilder.tomorrowAt(10,0,0))
        .build();
```

And then include some logic in your job to reschedule itself for the next day in the same way, upon finishing.
Alternatively, you can just schedule it to run every 5 minutes forever, and have the job check if it's between 8am and 10am before doing anything.

Or you could use, you know... a cron expression:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger() // identity, job, etc.
        .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0 0/5 8-10 * * ? *"))
        .startAt(DateBuilder.evenMinuteDateAfterNow())
        .build();
```

Which does exactly what you want -- that's what cron expressions are for.

Comment: Cron expression is useful when you using it with hours/days, etc, but when you want to use it by triggering between minutes or seconds (eg. 8:55 - 10:15 with some interval) it can involve issues (you can't provide correct expression for that problem). That why i would avoid this way. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Yes, I know the limits of cron expressions, but for the more reasonable example in your question they fit the bill. Those other schedules that are "not doable" with cron, I find them quite rare in production, but in the event that you actually need one you can apply my first solution (simple schedule for the intra-day scheduling and have the job do the day-to-day rescheduling).

Comment: Your solution is really helpful but what if I want execute job in the same day when i provided it? Actually i have to wait one day before day-to-day executing. Maybe triggering job (with method todayAt instead tommorowAt) by another job which will schedule to run every 24h (startAt 12am + interval 24h)?

Comment: I used `tomorrowAt` because that's what the job should do to properly reschedule itself. In our setup, initial scheduling of jobs is done during application startup (`RAMJobStore`), which can happen at any time; if we used `todayAt(8,0,0)` and the app restarted after 8am, the job would never run. Using `tomorrowAt` ensures it does. But yeah, _if you wanted to have it run the same day you're scheduling it_ (which you didn't mention), yes you could use `todayAt` (watch out for misfires). You could also just `startNow()` if the time of the first run is not important.

Comment: Also, maybe I wasn't clear but the rescheduling with `tomorrowAt` would be at the end of your job's `execute()` method, while the first `scheduleJob()` would be at a different part of your code (app initialization code, job scheduling UI, whatever). No need for a separate "scheduler job" IMHO.